# Need explanation about KeyId/CertId/CertPathId/PassPhraseId

Tags: c++, c++11, onvif

In onvif i come across the term KeyId/CertId/CertPathId and PassPhraseId what are these? How these are all created ?

Answer (score 0):

They are data types defined for the [ONVIF Security Service](https://www.onvif.org/specs/srv/security/ONVIF-Security-Service-Spec.pdf).
As you can see in [advancedsecurity.wsdl](http://view-source:https://www.onvif.org/ver10/advancedsecurity/wsdl/advancedsecurity.wsdl), they are all defined as `xs:NCName` with length 64.

Non Colonized Names are strings that stat with a letter or `_` and that cannot have colons.

In ONVIF these values are just used to reference keys, certificates and so on, you can think about them as regular tokens.