# Need explanation about KeyId/CertId/CertPathId in TLS Server

Tags: openssl, tls1.2, onvif

I have found explanation in [ [Need explanation about KeyId/CertId/CertPathId/PassPhraseId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55429432/need-explanation-about-keyid-certid-certpathid-passphraseid) ][1], and i use command

```
openssl dgst -sha1 -c -hex self_signed.crt
openssl dgst -sha1 -c -hex new_rsa_pub.key
```

to create KeyId/CertId/CertPathId, it works fine in Keystore and Certificate Management cases. But in  TLS Server cases, especially in Test Case ADVANCED_SECURITY-3-2-3, step 18,

*ONVIF Client verifies basic TLS handshake with expecting Server Certificate (in certPathID)using specified port (in portHTTPS) by following the procedure mentioned in Annex A.21.*

and in Annex A.21, the Certificate in ServerHello message:

*The DUT TLS server responds Certificate message with parameters*

- Certificate.CertificateID =: CertificateID
- Certificate.KeyID =: KeyID

Seems the KeyID/CertificateID must contain in the tls server's Certificate files and the KeyID/CertificateID must equal to the IDs which created by the command above...Nothing unexpected, the test failed...

So what exactly does keyID/CertificateID mean? How can i create these IDs with openssl?

thks!

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the source of [advancedsecurity.wsdl](https://www.onvif.org/ver10/advancedsecurity/wsdl/advancedsecurity.wsdl), KeyID and CertificateID are defined as:

```
<xs:simpleType name="KeyID">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Unique identifier for keys in the keystore.</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:NCName">
        <xs:maxLength value="64"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="CertificateID">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Unique identifier for certificates in the keystore.</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:NCName">
        <xs:maxLength value="64"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

As you can see, they are strings that you can freely define to identify keys and certificates.